# What does it mean if class.getProtectionDomain returns null

Tags: class

I have a method which returns the jar in which a particular class is loaded from. The method is below.
For some class the below line returns null

ProtectionDomain protectionDomain = c.getProtectionDomain();

I want to understand in what situation it is null. The code compiles so i think the class is visible at compile time and the dependency of the project in which the particular class lies also is a compile time dependency.

Here is the method

```
  public static String jarFor(Class c) {
    ProtectionDomain protectionDomain = c.getProtectionDomain();
    CodeSource codeSource = protectionDomain.getCodeSource();
    URL url = codeSource.getLocation();
    String path = url.getPath();
    if (Os.isWindows() && path.startsWith("/")) {
      path = path.substring(1);
    }
    return URLDecoder.decode(path);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getProtectionDomain%28%29) or the java code itself indicates that getProtectionDomain can return null.

```
public java.security.ProtectionDomain getProtectionDomain() {
    SecurityManager sm = System.getSecurityManager();
    if (sm != null) {
        sm.checkPermission(SecurityConstants.GET_PD_PERMISSION);
    }
    java.security.ProtectionDomain pd = getProtectionDomain0();
    if (pd == null) {
        if (allPermDomain == null) {
            java.security.Permissions perms = 
                new java.security.Permissions();
            perms.add(SecurityConstants.ALL_PERMISSION);
            allPermDomain = 
                new java.security.ProtectionDomain(null, perms);
        }
        pd = allPermDomain;
    }
    return pd;
}
```